Получить ссылку из стикера-ссылки истории телеграм с помощью telethon
Всех приветствую. В телеграме есть тип стикеров, когда выставляешь историю, в которые можно вшить ссылку. Мне нужно получить их с помощью telethon'а.
Пример таких ссылок:

я пробовал так:
result = await client.account.client(functions.stories.GetPinnedStoriesRequest(
        peer='https://t.me/some_peer',
offset_id=0,
limit=100))

for story in result.stories:
    print(story, "\n\n")

но элемент StoryItem не содержит информации именно по стикерам.
